# How to gray out a row of a table in Laravel 4?

Tags: html, css, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I want to gray out all the row(s) including **link** and **image**.

**This is what I got so far**

```
          @if ($user->active == 2)
          <tr class=" silver">
            @else
            <tr >
              @endif

              <td>
                // Stuff ...
              </td>

              </tr>
              @endforeach
            </tbody>
```

[image]

Comment: have you tried using css styles to set the background-color of cells?

Comment: No, I have not. My goal is gray out all the texts including my logo. I'm not intend to change any background color.

Comment: then you can set the text `color` attribute.  If there are bitmap images, then I'd think setting their transparency may be the easiest...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you already have a class assigned, so all you need is do some additional css. I suppose this is what you're doing now:

```
.silver { /* you probably want to use a more specific selector */
    color:#ccc;
}
```

Now we need to target the link and the image and the link separately

```
.silver a {
    color:#ccc; /* or some light turquoise if you want */
}
.silver img {
    opacity:0.4;
}
```

or:

#### The much simpler way

```
.silver {
    opacity:0.4;
}
```

However that gives you less control over the style of each element

Comment: Precisely ! Awesome Answer. I will do that now.